# In app purchase alert view is not displaying

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I am new in this field and want to integrate in app purchase in my application. I have successfully made in app purchase running with all functionalities and tested it various time and also it shown correct results. But now on clicking buy button in app purchase alert view is not coming both in my device and simulator. Have any one got this problem before.

Please suggest any solution for the above mentioned problem.

Comment: do you have set them up in ITC?